# repeating values by using group by in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services

Currently I am getting below output after using Parent group is Country field and child group is State field. Why india is repeating but USA data looks good.

```
country --------    state -----   Products sold

INDIA------------- MP------------            400

INDIA--------------   HP  ------------            200

USA --------------   FL------------            110

                   CA-------- 220

                     NY--------100
```

How to get the below output?

```
country --------    state -----   Products sold

INDIA------------- MP------------            400

                  HP  ------------            200

USA --------------   FL------------            110

                   CA-------- 220

                     NY--------100
```

Comment: Have you set the **Hide Duplicates** property of your group to your Group Name?

Comment: Check your data, No space before/after INDIA.